# I fail to see how plotting these points help to conclude the lines are parallel

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[Final question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuwkr.jpg)

I guessed "there is no line" and the test told me the answer is "the lines are parallel to the x-axis."

Comment: I'm not sure what the ordered pairs are for, but I see a bunch of lines in the plot, that are parallel with the x-axis.

Comment: The problem would make more sense to me if "lines" were not plural in the proposed answer. Seems pretty poorly written.

Comment: Sure, But, maybe this is "ticky tack," but strictly speaking those are line segments and not lines.  And yeah, what do the ordered pairs have to do with anything?  The question implies plotting the ordered pairs leads to the answer.

Comment: I think it's a poorly made question, whose intentions are not clear. I can't argue that it is "wrong," though.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Another thing about the "lines."  There is no way to tell for sure that they are parallel.  Yes they do look parallel.  But they don't have to be.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is assumed that the points are plotted on a graph, it is implicit that the graph is a line and it is parallel to the x-axis, which in this case it is the x-axis.

Comment: Not sure I agree with that "implicit" part.  But the answer says lines, plural.  Apparently referring to the other, apparently parallel, lines shown.

Comment: Lines are obviously parallel to the x-axis but I do not see the relevance to the ordered pairs. May be the ordered pairs are there to show us which line is the x-axis.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani: Aha! I think you've figured out what the question meant. The plotted points let you identify which axis is the $x$-axis.